# Retrieving data from chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous

I'm trying to retrieve data from `chrome.storage.sync.get` but I'm unable to do so. `chrome.storage.sync.get` is async and I'm using a callback, but I think I'm missing something.

```
function getSnippetsIds(callback) {

  chrome.storage.sync.get("snippets.ids", function(data) {
  var ids = [];
  for (var key in data['snippets.ids']) {
    if ( data['snippets.ids'][key] === true ) {
      ids.push(key);
    }
  }       
   callback(ids);
  });

}

var test;

// callback function
function logVal(val) {
  test =  val.join(',');
  return test;
}
console.log(test) // undefined    

var snippetsIds = getSnippetsIds( logVal );
console.log(snippetsIds) // undefined
```

Expected output:
`console.log(snippetsIds) // [Array]`

Now with an object:

```
var snippetIds = {} 
function logVal(val) {
  snippetIds.value = val.join(',');
}

getSnippetsIds( logVal );
```

1. `console.log(snippetIds)`

   [image: output]
2. `console.log(snippetIds.value) // undefined`

Working example:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set( { myStorageKey: 'any value' } );

var store = {};
chrome.storage.sync.get('myStorageKey', function(obj) {  
 store.val = obj;
});
console.log(store); // empty
console.log(store.val); // undefined
```

Comment: can you try with bracket notation - `snippetIds['value']`

Comment: @KalpeshSingh Still undefined. `console.log( _.isEmpty(snippetIds) )` returns `true`.

Comment: A working example would be great! Can you share?

Comment: @KalpeshSingh See edit.